# excerpt display same text

Tags: excerpt

I start learning Wordpress from scratch then i decided to put the 5 latest post in sidebar, and the code is alright and when i decided to add description using `excerpt`, excerpt desplay same text can someone guide me what should i do, what should i improve, 

any idea is appreciated thank's in advance!
 [image: thumbnail with excerpt]

here is my current code:

```
    <ul class="lalest">
<?php
$IDOutsideLoop = $post->ID;
global $post;

$myposts = get_posts('showposts=5');
foreach($myposts as $post) :
?>
    <li>
    <div class="thumb">
      <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($page->ID, 'thumbnail'); ?>
    </div>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
      <?php the_title(); ?>
      </a>
             <?php the_excerpt(); ?>

      </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to be using [`setup_postdata($post);`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/setup_postdata) as in all of the examples for [`get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts#Examples). You need:

```
$myposts = get_posts('numberposts=5');
foreach($myposts as $post) :
    setup_postdata($post);
    // the rest of your function
```